# Unable to slice element from a tuple element in a dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to calculate the sum of the 1st index of each tuple element in a list that is the value of a dictionary. Finally, I would calculate the average.

```
{"Example": [(0, 10), (1, 10), (2,30)]}
```

For example, the sum of this should be 50 as it is adding from the 1st index of each tuple element.

The code:

```
dict1 = {"Example": [(0, 64), (1, 64), (2, 64)}
get_sum = 0
for key in dict1[key]:
    values = dict1[key]
    get_sum += values[i][1] #<---- error originates from here

freq = len(dict1[key])
get_avg = (get_sum // freq)
print(sum={},avg={}).format(get_sum, get_avg)
```

However, I am getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuples.
The output should be:

```
sum={192}
avg={64.0}
```

Comment: Where did `i` and,  `key` of `dict1[key]` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code just loop through the dict using key and find sum using list comprehension then avg , you can print according to your format:

```
dict1 = {"Example": [(0, 64), (1, 64), (2, 64)]}
for key in dict1:
    value = dict1[key]
    Sum = sum([j for (i,j) in value])
    print("sum = ",Sum)
    print("avg = " ,Sum/len(value))
```

output:

```
sum =  192
avg =  64.0
```